# Problems compiling Ruby 2.4.2

Tags: ruby, gcc, rubygems, autotools

I am trying to build a minimal easily transportable Ruby without relying on external projects, just for my own learning process.

I am using `otool -L ruby` to determine what libraries the Ruby binary is dynamically linking against as I am trying to minimize it.

Yesterday when i built Ruby it only dynamically linked against 3 libraries, however today when i build Ruby it is linking against 13. I have no idea what has changed between yesterday and today but I am thoroughly confused -- especially as many of the libraries it is linking against existed prior to yesterday's compilation.

On Yesterday's Ruby executable the result of `otool -L` was:

```
otool -L ruby
ruby:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1349.8.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 489.0.0)
```

But today it is:

```
otool -L ./ruby
./ruby:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1349.8.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libutil.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 489.0.0)
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

I am compiling Ruby 2.4.2 like so:

```
X="-arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
CFLAGS="$X" CXXFLAGS="$X" LDFLAGS="$X" ./configure --prefix=/tmp/ruby-deploy --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)  --disable-install-doc --without-gmp
```

Comment: If you did the same thing today that you did yesterday, but got different results, then it follows that something changed on your system.  That could have been something in your project directory, but it could also be elsewhere in your system.  I don't see how we can answer the question, other than by guessing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i figured the issue, posted below :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was that I had also run:

`CFLAGS="$X" CXXFLAGS="$X" LDFLAGS="$X" ./configure --prefix=/tmp/ruby-deploy --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-static-linked-ext --disable-install-doc --without-gmp`

at one point -- note the `--with-static-linked-ext`. This resulted in the other dynamically linked libs.

However because i had subsequently run `./configure` again WITHOUT that option i assumed it would have reset the configuration, but it didn't.

I discovered the problem by wiping out the Ruby source folder and re-fetching from github. Running the initial `./configure` (excluding the `--with-static-linked-ext` resolved the issue!